# Rails: How to ensure clean state for test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

please help solve the problem.

factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :album do
    sequence(:title){ |i| "title#{i}" }
    user_id 1
    closed nil
    description 'g dgd fghf ghj gj gj gj gj g'
  end
end
```

albums_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe AlbumsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'show action' do
    it 'render show template if user and album is found' do
      album = FactoryGirl.create(:album)
      get :show, { user_id: 1, id: album.id }
      response.should render_template('show')
      response.should render_template "layouts/application"
    end
  end  
end
```

album model:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum:  50, minimum: 3 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum:  600, minimum: 10 }

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images
end
```

i run in console:

```
rspec spec
```

console display follow:

```
OK
Finished in 0.28618 seconds (files took 1.91 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

but I again run the command:

```
rspec spec
```

and console display error message:

```
ERROR: record is exist!
rspec ./spec/controllers/albums_controller_spec.rb:14 # AlbumsController show action render show template if user and album is found
```

that there are no mistakes, I have to run every time:

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

but it is inconvenient. please tell me, is it possible not to enter this command(db:reset) every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem to ensure a clean state for testing.

You can configure your RSpec like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Then, you will be able to run your spec only with `rspec spec` command without resetting the database manually every time.